# Expected number of edges left after edge-self-avoiding random walk on complete graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $K_n$ be the complete graph on $n$ vertices, and consider the following non-Markov process:

- start at an arbitrary vertex of the graph.
- until you "get stuck," repeat the following: choose an edge uniformly at random that is adjacent to your current vertex. Traverse that edge, and then delete it.

Let $f(n)$ be the expected number of edges that remain in the graph $K_n$ after you "get stuck." Is there a closed-form formula for $f(n)$? An asymptotic bound?

---

Computing $f(n)$ exactly is intractable except for very small $n$ (brute-force enumeration of all walks requires $O(2^{n^2})$ computation), but here is some Monte Carlo simulation data (in blue) along with a fit line $g(n) = \frac{n}{2}$ (in red):

[image] [image]

The parity of $n$ has a significant effect on $f(n)$; this behavior is intuitively unsurprising since when $n$ is odd, you can only get stuck at your starting vertex (since all vertices have even valence) whereas for $n$ even, you can get stuck at any vertex *except* your starting vertex. Eyeballing the above plots suggests that $f(n)$ is slightly super-linear when $n$ even, and linear when $n$ is odd (with a linear fit strongly suggestive that $f(2n+1) \sim n$). Is there a way to understand this behavior theoretically?